# IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray, reinforcement-learning, index-error

The code I have shared below is getting an error, has anyone encountered a similar error?

```
import numpy as np
import gym
import random

ENV_NAME = "Taxi-v3"
env = gym.make(ENV_NAME)

print("Number of actions: %d" % env.action_space.n)
print("Number of states: %d" % env.observation_space.n)

action = env.action_space.n
state = env.observation_space.n

qtable = np.zeros((state, action),dtype=int)
print(qtable)

total_episodes = 50000
total_test_episodes = 5
max_steps = 99

learning_rate = 0.7
discount_rate = 0.9

epsilon = 1
max_epsilon = 1
min_epsilon = 0.01
decay_rate = 0.01

for episode in range(total_episodes):
    
    state = env.reset()
    step = 0
    done = False
    
    for step in range(max_steps):

        exp_exp_tradeoff = random.uniform(0,1)
        
      
        if exp_exp_tradeoff > epsilon:
            action = np.argmax(qtable[state, :])

        else:
            action = env.action_space.sample()
        
        new_state, reward, terminated, done, info = env.step(action)
        
        qtable[state, action] = qtable[state, action] + learning_rate * (reward + discount_rate * np.max(qtable[new_state, :]) - qtable[state, action])
        state = new_state
        
        if done is True:
            break
    
    episode += 1
  
    epsilon = min_epsilon + (max_epsilon - min_epsilon) * np.exp(-decay_rate * episode)
```

I'm getting the following error, I cant figure it out

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_1092/2436469204.py in <module>
     51         #Update q value for the state based on the formula
     52         #Q(s,a) = Q(s,a) + lr[R(s,a) + gamma * max Q(s',a') - Q(s,a)]
---> 53         qtable[state, action] = qtable[state, action] + learning_rate * (reward + discount_rate * np.max(qtable[new_state, :]) - qtable[state, action])
     54         state = new_state
     55 

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

please help me

Answer (score 1):

##### The problem

The problem is with this line of code:

```
state = env.reset()
```

it returns a tuple that looks like this:

```
(12, {'prob': 1.0, 'action_mask': array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int8)})
```

which I saw by adding `print(state)` just before the line that's giving you an error. That's not an int or anything that can be used as an index, hence the error you got.

##### The fix

Since you seem to want just the state's index, I think this is what you meant to do:

```
state = env.reset()[0]
```

When I make that change to your code, it runs for many iterations without errors.

##### My troubleshooting approach: print debugging

When you get this kind of error, you can try to run the code in a debugger and inspect your variables--it's worth learning to use a debugger if you don't know how--but my first approach is to just add print statements to see what my variables look like, often that's enough to make it obvious.

I augmented your code to this and the problem was immediately obvious:

```
    ...
    print("state", state)
    print("action", action)
    print("new_state", new_state)
    print("qtable", qtable)
    qtable[state, action] = qtable[state, action] + learning_rate * (reward + discount_rate * np.max(qtable[new_state, :]) - qtable[state, action])
    ...
```